# VBA Compile error: Object required trying to set data into a class

Tags: excel, vba

It has been a while since I have programmed in VBA. I wanted to clean up my code and make it a bit more readable to future me. So I started to make some classes. Here is my simplified problem:

```
'class code ' class is called cls_curriculum_object
Dim m_curriculum_object_name As String

Public Property Get curriculum_object_name()
    curriculum_object_name = m_curriculum_object_name
End Property

Public Property Set curriculum_object_name(curriculum_object_name)
    m_curriculum_object_name = curriculum_object_name
End Property


' button code
Dim cls_curriculum_object As cls_curriculum_object
Set cls_curriculum_object = New cls_curriculum_object

ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Select
Set cls_curriculum_object.curriculum_object_name = Trim(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1)

' if I run it. It works fine but if I change the code to
Set cls_curriculum_object.curriculum_object_name = "foo"
' I get a VBA compile error message
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `Dim myClassCO as New cls_curriculum_object`. Then, `MyClassCO.curriculum_object_name = Trim(ActiveCell.value)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `String` and need [`Property Let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-let-statement), not `Property Set`:

```
Public Property Let curriculum_object_name(curriculum_object_name)
    m_curriculum_object_name = curriculum_object_name
End Property

...

cls_curriculum_object.curriculum_object_name = Trim(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1)
cls_curriculum_object.curriculum_object_name = "foo"
```

Side note, but *snake_case* is very unreadable.

Comment: BigBen thank you very much!! What's popular now camel case? Kind of force of habit with my snake case, I use the same system going right back to the database.

Comment: Not necessarily a question of "popular", but for example the Excel VBA Object Model doesn't use snake_case: it's `ActiveCell`, not `Active_Cell`. For that matter, neither does the VBA library.